# Why am I receiving these Google Apps Script reports? What are they?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

```
Error Message   Count
Authorization is required to perform that action.   25
Start   Function    Error Message   Trigger End
8/7/21 8:10:51 PM GMT   triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/7/21 8:10:51 PM GMT
8/7/21 9:10:51 PM GMT   triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/7/21 9:10:51 PM GMT
8/7/21 10:10:51 PM GMT  triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/7/21 10:10:51 PM GMT
8/7/21 11:10:51 PM GMT  triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/7/21 11:10:51 PM GMT
8/8/21 12:10:51 AM GMT  triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/8/21 12:10:51 AM GMT
8/8/21 1:10:51 AM GMT   triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/8/21 1:10:51 AM GMT
8/8/21 2:10:51 AM GMT   triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/8/21 2:10:51 AM GMT
8/8/21 3:10:51 AM GMT   triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/8/21 3:10:51 AM GMT
8/8/21 4:10:51 AM GMT   triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/8/21 4:10:51 AM GMT
8/8/21 5:10:51 AM GMT   triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/8/21 5:10:51 AM GMT
8/8/21 6:10:51 AM GMT   triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/8/21 6:10:51 AM GMT
8/8/21 7:10:51 AM GMT   triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/8/21 7:10:51 AM GMT
8/8/21 8:10:51 AM GMT   triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/8/21 8:10:51 AM GMT
8/8/21 9:10:51 AM GMT   triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/8/21 9:10:51 AM GMT
8/8/21 10:10:51 AM GMT  triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/8/21 10:10:51 AM GMT
8/8/21 11:10:51 AM GMT  triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/8/21 11:10:51 AM GMT
8/8/21 12:10:51 PM GMT  triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/8/21 12:10:51 PM GMT
8/8/21 1:10:56 PM GMT   triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/8/21 1:10:57 PM GMT
8/8/21 2:10:51 PM GMT   triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/8/21 2:10:51 PM GMT
8/8/21 3:10:51 PM GMT   triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/8/21 3:10:51 PM GMT
8/8/21 4:10:51 PM GMT   triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/8/21 4:10:51 PM GMT
8/8/21 5:10:51 PM GMT   triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/8/21 5:10:51 PM GMT
8/8/21 6:10:51 PM GMT   triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/8/21 6:10:51 PM GMT
8/8/21 7:10:51 PM GMT   triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/8/21 7:10:51 PM GMT
8/8/21 8:10:51 PM GMT   triggerEmailStudio  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  8/8/21 8:10:51 PM GMT
Sincerely,

Google Apps Script
```

Comment: Have you installed an add-on for Google Documents, Forms Sheets or Slides recently? Have you used Google Apps Script before?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the Apps Script project needs your authorization to continue with its function, there are two ways to solve this problem:

1. Go to the Apps Script project and perform a manual run to renew the permissions:
   [image]
   or
2. Remove the triggers from that project and create them again
   [image]
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving the reports because Google Apps Script installable triggers by default send a daily summary of error messages when they happen. An installable trigger could be created by using code, the Apps Script editor / "hub", by add-ons or third party applications.

If you didn't created the triggers, then is very likely that a add-on or an application that you authorized is the responsible of the creation of those triggers.   The authorization might be required again if you removed the authorization from the Google Account settings but didn't uninstalled the add-on or when the programmer changes the add-on / application authorization scopes.